# using c# dll in project c++

Tags: c#, c++

i want use dll made in c#(visual studio 2008) in c++ project(visual studio 2003). how to do that ? please heeelp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use c# Dll in vc++??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980808/how-to-use-c-dll-in-vc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a DLL created using C# in an unmanaged VC++ application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873714/is-it-possible-to-use-a-dll-created-using-c-in-an-unmanaged-vc-application)

Comment: @0xA3: I'm curious, how would VC++ 2008 make things easier? Code compiled in VC 2003 can include COM components, and it can include any kind of native wrapper DLL, even if it's written in VC2008, right?

Comment: @nikie: As far as I know the VC++ /CLR option would require that both the C++ and the C# dll are using the same .NET runtime version. VS2003 is still targeting the old .NET 1.1.

Comment: @0xA3: True, but he could write the C++/CLR wrapper DLL in VC 2008, and include it in his existing VC2003 project, without upgrading his existing project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is more than just COM interop, the **[MSDN FAQ](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/adce905c-2bd3-4276-be53-c644dd928dfa)** also lists lesser known methods:

> **2.2 How do I call .NET assembly from native Visual C++?**
>
> There are basically four methods to
>   call .NET assembly from native VC++
>   code. Microsoft [All-In-One Code Framework](http://cfx.codeplex.com/) has working examples that
>   demonstrate the methods.
>
> 1. Native VC++ module calls [CLR Hosting APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx) to host CLR, load and
>      call the .NET assembly. (All-In-One
>      Code Framework Sample Code:
>      CppHostCLR)
> 2. If the .NET assembly can be exposed as a COM component, native
>      VC++ module can call into the .NET
>      assembly through .NET – COM interop.
>      (All-In-One Code Framework Sample
>      Code: CppCOMClient)
> 3. Reverse PInvoke: the managed code call native passing a delegate
>      the native code can call back.
>      (All-In-One Code Framework Sample
>      Code: CSPInvokeDll)
> 4. If the module containing native VC++ code is allowed to [enable CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173265.aspx), the native VC++ code can call
>      .NET assembly directly through the “It
>      Just Works”, or “IJW”, mechanism. (All-In-One Code Framework Sample Code: CppCLIWrapLib)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use .NET assemblies from unmanaged C++ code. One possible solution is to expose the assembly as COM object using the [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx) utility and then consume it from C++. Note that .NET types that need to be exposed as COM objects might need to be decorated with the [`[COMVisible(true)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) attribute and would still require the .NET framework installed on the target computer running the C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

Is the C# DLL a COM DLL?  If so you can use the regular COM API/Specification to access it in your C++ program.  There are many tutorials on making your C# DLL COM visible.  It's not that difficult, a few compile switches and C# attributes basically.

Otherwise, can you compile your C++ project using the [/clr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx) compiler switch?  If so you can use the [Using Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewtdfs3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to import your C# DLL directly.

Answer (score 1):

As Darin said, one way is via COM. The other two ways (I know of) are:

- You can create a mixed-mode DLL in C++. That DLL can contain and call managed code, but it can also export unmanaged functions, like a normal C++ DLL. It can be included like any other C++ DLL
- It's a lot harder, but you can also host the CLR. Google for "CLR hosting" to find details about the API or samples.

Answer (score 1):

after setting the "Resolve #using References" (Project->C/C++->General) compiler option to the directory containing the assembly you want, then you put a line like this in your code.

```
#using <NiftyAssembly.dll>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make library file [.Tlb ] file and then only we can use the dll's. You have to make .TLB (Type Library file) of your original c# DLL and use that.TLB library in the VC++ code. For that you have to register .TLB file on your pc as well as it is neccessary to import that .TLB file in your vc++ apllication.
When you write C# DLL remember to use interfaces that would be implemented in the class.