# Integrating a .NET C# program into a compiled (unmanaged) C++ program (without having to execute a separate .exe file)

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I have some .NET C# code that I want to execute through a compiled (unmanaged) C++ program.

Currently what I have done is to put the former into a separate .exe file, which I execute from the C++ program. (The C++ program executes the .exe file, passing in the proper arguments, and captures its output into a variable.)

This works. However, executing a separate .exe file introduces some overhead, and the overhead is noticeable - one notices a half a second gap or so while the .exe program runs and finishes.

Question: Are there any better ways to do such integration? Something that would be faster than executing an .exe.

I'm on Windows XP running Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: You should be able to do this using the native CLR host APIs.

Comment: You do understand there is likely still going to be this 1 second gap right?

Comment: If you are running the managed program repeatedly, you may find it more efficient to re-engineer it as a persistent service.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this link useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx

You can create mixed mode assemblies that contain both native code and .NET code. However this is usually done using C++/CLR.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is only to execute specific code in the C# project you can simply build it as a dll and add it as a reference in the C++ project. From there you can execute parts of the C# code base as you please.

This question [using c# dll in project c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799907/using-c-sharp-dll-in-project-c) explains how to use the C# assembly in a project compiled with VC++

Answer (score 0):

One another way of integrating .NET with C++ would be through COM interface. Turn the .NET into COM component. Instantiate and invoke them from C++ is simple and fast enough. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In one of our business solutions we had to connect an unmanaged c++ application to a managed c# application. 
We achieved that by creating one mixed mode "Wrapper" dll, one managed c# "Client" dll on the unmanaged application side and one WCF service with a NamedPipe-Binding, hostet by the managed c# application.

The unmanaged c++ application calls the wrapper, which redirects the request to the c# Client dll. That dll establishes the connection to the WCF service of the c# Application and calls the requested Method on that service.