# Can a function written in C# can be called in C language?

Tags: c#, c, windows, dll

Let's say I'm writing a C# class with a simple method  which returns a int type for example. I build the project which is a class library and then I obtain a dll. Can I use that dll to call that simple method but in C language?

I've been doing some research and I found out that is possible if a have a dll written in c, and called in C# but nothing about the vice versa scenario.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not in any simple way. See this relevant question, it may apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257428/reverse-pinvoke-from-native-c . It's asked for C++, but I don't enough about the differences to say it's also relevant for C.

Comment: Have a look to https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports that may help you. I tried it to wrap a C# .NET dll and used it from Delphi as a native dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so straightforward. Since C# is a managed language, it run in a sort of infrastructure, ant to call it from another language outside the dotnet environment you have to host such environment. 
You can have a look here to start working on: [CorBindToRuntimeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99sz37yh(v=vs.110).aspx). If you can work with C++ the less painful integration is C++ / CLI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx#S1 that allow you to mix call in C/c++ with call to c# libraries in a quite low friction way.