# Finding a .Net DLL in (.Net) C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I'm a C# programmer who hasn't used C++ since the pre-.Net days.

I have a C# .Net DLL that I use with other C# programs.   In the calling program in Visual Studio I simply do an "Add Resource..." and a Using" statement in the code that calls into it and voilà! there it is.

Now I have a customer who wants to access our DLL in a Visual Studio 2010 **C++** (CLI) program.  So I want to make a practice C++ program that uses our DLL.  What's the equivalent of Add Reference in a C++/CLI project and what do I put in the program to expose the namespace for my DLL?    Where does the DLL have to physically be?  In the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio for the C++ project I don't see the same things as I do in a C# project.

Comment: It's been a long time for me, too, but I think you'd have to make the DLL COM-compliant, regsvr32 that baby and then access it like a COM component.

Comment: I doubt it's that complicated - modern C++ is a .Net (CLI/CLR) language.

Comment: He is running in the .Net framework.  This is all CLI, all .Net.    There are lots of people who use .Net who prefer to program in C++.

Comment: To be fair, there aren't many .NET developers who prefer to code in C++. It's doable, but is overly verbose. In my experience the only time people choose to do it is when they need to interface with a C++ or C library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project in Visual Studio, and select "References".  You should have a dialog with a few references already attached ("System" and a few others perhaps).  Click "Add New Reference" and browse to the assembly (or project if it's in the same solution) that you want to use.

Comment: Excellent.  It looks different from a C# project so I didn't recognize it, but everything seems to be there.   Yeah, I didn't think it would be hard but it's interesting how many people saw C++ and just assumed "unmanaged" and made this question harder than it was.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the knowledgebase on calling native (.net) code from c++? It is about Visual Studio 2005, but the process should be the same.

[How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736)

And there is a related (identical) question on here as well:

[using c# dll in project c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799907/using-c-sharp-dll-in-project-c)

---

Edit since I missed the bit where it's about a **managed** C++ project:

[How to add references to a managed Visual C++ project](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310674)

> **.NET references**
> .NET references point to shared assemblies. For example, the assembly System.Windows.Forms.dll is a standard assembly for accessing the Windows Forms classes. In order to use this assembly in a Managed C++ application, you simply have to reference it with a #using preprocessor directive, as shown here:
>
> `#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>`

Comment: This isn't a managed/unmanaged situation.  This is a current Visual Studio .Net C++ program so it's all managed.  It's all CLI.

Comment: If it is managed, it should offer you the "Add References" dialog just like C#.

Comment: Do you know this for a fact?  I just created a new C++ CLR project (In Visual Studio 2010, New Project->Other Languages->Visual C++ -> CLR) for .Net 4.0 and I don't see it.