# Using x86 DLL in an unreal engine Win64 C++ class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, x86, unreal-engine4

I have written code in a .NET Framework C++ file. The code uses the `Articares` DLL to connect with the device through an IP address. Where `instance` is simply creating an instance of the classes I want to use from the DLL. `instance.EstablishConnection()` is the function i want to call from the class.
The below code works perfectly in x86.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include<cstring>
#include <vector>
#include "Complex.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace Articares;
using namespace NLog;

int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    //Creating instances of the classes ----------------------------------------------------
    Articares::Core::ArticaresComm instance;
    Articares::Core::HMANData instance2;
    Articares::Core::TargetParams instance3;

    //Connecting to HMan -------------------------------------------------------------------
    instance.EstablishConnection("192.168.102.1", 3000);
    std::cout << "Connection with HMan established\n";
   return 0;
}
```

However, i want to be able to use the DLLs in the unreal engine C++ file to replicate this code i have written.

But the error  `name must be a namespace name` appears when i try to declare the DLLs in the unreal engine C++ file.

Could anybody tell me how to fix this problem to be able to use my x86 DLLs in the unreal engine C++ code?

Thanks.

Comment: `name must be a namespace name`  On which line the error occurred?

Comment: @Minxin Yu, the ````name must be a namespace```` has occurred at  ```` using namespace Articares ````  and ````using namespace NLog```` however i have added both of these Dlls as references and they work perfectly in the functioning code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using C++ DLL or . NET DLL?

For C++ DLL, you need to add dependencies.   [Walkthrough: Create and use your own Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170)

For .NET DLL, You are calling managed code in unmanaged C++.
Use [Exposing .NET components to COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/exposing-dotnet-components-to-com?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

For your reference: [using c# dll in project c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799907/using-c-sharp-dll-in-project-c)