# Using C# as C Style export Library

Tags: c#, c, interop

while using C Style Export libs in .net is quite easy thanks to the platform invocation servies, I have no clue how to export a C# lib in C Style.
I want to use C# to extend existing applications, the best interface I have is a C Style import capeablility. Any suggestions/ideas/hits?

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call C++/CLI (.NET) DLLs from standard, unmanaged non-.NET applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852428/how-do-i-call-c-cli-net-dlls-from-standard-unmanaged-non-net-applications)

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially 3 ways of doing Native Managed interop:

- COM interop - expose everything via COM which is accessible both in C# and native code.
- Managed C++ - created a managed C++ assembly which is capable of running both managed and native code.
- Host the CLR inside a native process.  I've included this for completeness, but most of the time either managed C++ or COM interop are better solutions.

See [How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code (KB)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736) for some more detail on first two of the above method.

(I know that this is all aimed at C++ not C, but the challenge here is the native / managed intops part - these techniques can either be modified to work with C instead of C++, or other techniques can be used to call C++ code from C)

Comment: The techniques to export into c++ are well known and proven to be a pain in the neck. Adding another layer to wrap from c++ to c seems even more painfull.

Comment: @Jaster Then I'm afraid if COM is not an option this leaves you with hosting the CLR inside your own process, which is going to be even more painful again I'm afraid!